# Interfacing Windows.h with GLFW.h

Tags: c++

I want to build an application whereby I can rotate a  3D cube using an accelerometer (hardware is complete).

I a coding in C++ using an OpenGL API, I am able to create windows with both windows.h and glfw.h libraries. The reason why I am using windows.h is that I want to implement buttons.

Can I create all my graphics using the GLFW functions in a parent window that I created? Because I see that windows use handles while glfw uses GLFWwindow* window;

I would like to know if this is possible? if not how must I go about this to tackle the task?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this has nothing to do with *Electrical Engineering*.

Comment: Anything is possible if you program it properly but since you didn't ask `If so, how much I go about this to tackle the task?` I guess my journey with this question ends here.

Answer (score 1):

A GLFW window is indeed just a window. You can obtain its native handle through [`glfwGetWin32Window`](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/group__native.html#gafe5079aa79038b0079fc09d5f0a8e667).